# Javascript SDK Testing of FB.ui on localhost domain inconsistency issues

Tags: localhost, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ui

When I try to test on localhost sharing a link via FB.ui I get the following error:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

This makes sense since in my app I set the site location. Is there any way to get this to work locally? Should i make another app which points to localhost?

Answer (score 0):

That's usually the easiest way to do it. When we start a new project we generally create several apps: one for each developer's local testing, another for the staging/sandbox environment, and another for the live application.

You can also try to spoof the domain locally, though I haven't tried this method in long time.